# R package gamlss used inside foreach() fails to find an object

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, gamlss

I'm trying to get leave-one-out predicted values. Please help me with this "can't find object" issue. I have searched for similar issues, but haven't managed to figure it out. This is on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

```
library('gamlss')
library('foreach')
library('doParallel')

registerDoParallel(cores = 4)
# Generate data
set.seed(314)
sample.size <- 30
input.processed.cut <- data.frame(TP = round(runif(sample.size) * 100), 
                                  FP = round(runif(sample.size) * 100), 
                                  x = runif(sample.size))
# Fit Beta-binomial
model3 <- gamlss(formula = cbind(TP, FP) ~ x,   
                 family = BB,  
                 data = input.processed.cut) 

# Get the leave-one-out values
loo_predict.mu <- function(model.obj, input.data) {
  yhat <- foreach(i = 1 : nrow(input.data), .packages="gamlss", .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    updated.model.obj <- update(model.obj, data = input.data[-i, ])
    predict(updated.model.obj, what = "mu", newdata = input.data[i,], type = "response")
  }
  return(data.frame(result = yhat[, 1], row.names = NULL))
}

par.run <- loo_predict.mu(model3, input.processed.cut)
# Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'input.data' not found" 

> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

Comment: @akrun It seems to me that the problem is not caused by `foreach` (although stated by the OP). To see that, just replace `%dopar%` by `%do`. My opinion is that this problem is a bug from package {gamlss}.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I made corrections.

Comment: Could you please explain this: if switching from do to dopar breaks it, it must be dopar's fault, right? Why should it be gamlss?

Comment: I also get the error using only `%do%` (sequentially), this is why. The `object not found` is a common error with foreach-parallel (as reported by @akrun) because the object is not passed to the clusters. But this error arises only in the parallel version.

Comment: I came across a similar posting about an lm object, but it didn't help. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Arguments-to-lm-within-a-function-object-not-found-td864634.html

Comment: Maybe try to find the GitHub associated with the package and open an issue there. Or email the author.

Comment: I emailed them via gamlss.org and gave them a link to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from gamlss team and verified that their solution works. The only thing to change was to provide "data" along with "newdata" to predict().

```
loo_predict.mu <- function(model.obj, input.data) {
  yhat <- foreach(i = 1 : nrow(input.data), .packages="gamlss", .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    updated.model.obj <- update(model.obj, data = input.data[-i, ])
    predict(updated.model.obj, what = "mu", data = input.data[-i, ],
            newdata = input.data[i,], type = "response")
  }
  return(data.frame(result = yhat[, 1], row.names = NULL))
}
```